# Directive array element not showing in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/H62CoDwNJMLplpolRrlM?p=preview) I have a table with ng-repeat, where one of the elements in the table is a directive. Problem is that directive field is not showing in the table. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
    <table border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td>
            {{row.x}}
        </td>            
        <td>
            <div some-directive field="row.field"></div>
        </td>            
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope) {

    $scope.rows = [{x: 1}, {x:2}];

});

app.directive('someDirective', function () {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = {    
            field: '='
    };

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.field = "aaa";
    };

    return directive;
});
```

Comment: Your directive doesn't have a template. Why would it display anything?

Comment: thanks, the template was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add directive.template = "{{field}}";